# Classic ASP to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic

I am currently working with a classic asp application.  We are looking to upgrade this in small phases to .NET.  what I mean by small phases is page by page over an extended period of time.

I want to minimize impact to users.  So upgrade pages but keeping the look the same for now.  The classic asp app is all frames based so I think i could keep the look and run the upgraded page and point to the new page?

My questions are, what is the best method in doing this in peoples experience?  Again I want to build this in .NET so I don't know if i would be best off using MVC or asp.net?  would utilizing a particular framework make any difference here?

Those folks who have went through this pain in the past what were some gotchyas in upgrading and running a newer technology with an older technology?   I would imagine i shouldn't have to much heartache in running these together.

Any additional things we should think about?

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204441/how-to-migrate-applications-from-classic-asp-to-asp-net-mvc?rq=1

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539123/migrating-classic-asp-webforms-or-asp-net-mvc?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC provides more control and flexibility. You can use .cshtml page to insert html code and use model variables (@Model.xxx with Razor) defined in your .cs code. You can easily display list box, combo box and other controls. Besides it does not require AJAX.